# jQuery slideshow - Including small portion of previous and next slides on either sides of the current/active slide

Tags: jquery

I usually use the excellent "jQuery Cycle Plugin" for my slideshow needs.

However, in this instance the client has created a design where we would like to show a small portion of the previous slide, and a small portion of the next slide (on either sides of the current/active slide).  I've included a simplified graphic to do most of the explaining.

[Simplified graphic of my desired slideshow setup http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/9916/slidedemo.gif](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/9916/slidedemo.gif)

I can handle the CSS regarding the opacity being lowered for the prev/next slides, but I don't have a clue how to edit the JS / jQuery code to enable something like this.

The Cycle Plugin has a wealth of parameters / options - and here is a page that illustrates horizontal sliding:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html

However, it doesn't include the previous/next slides.

I'm aware that it might be easier to find a different slideshow script altogether than trying to edit this particular one, but I've gone through countless scripts via Google searching, and none of them have yet to be what I'm looking for.

Any ideas / advice / tips are greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one does what you need:

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/

However, I'm not quite sure how well it works in iPhones and older versions of Explorer.